# How to access a variable in stored procedure into a sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to access a variable that is present in a stored procedure

e.g.

```
Create or Replace package body ABC
as 

    Procedure XYZ 
    as
    var Number;
    var := 2+3

    END XYZ

END ABC
```

Now I want to access this variable `var` in a select statement. Calling a the body.procedure.variable name work?
e.g.

```
select something as new_variable from table_name where ABC.XYZ.var > 10;
```

Comment: Then use a function or return out parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can only access package variables from an external query if they are declared in the package header.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST is

var  VARCHAR2(10);
 /*or use the function*/
FUNCTION get_var RETURN VARCHAR2;
END TEST;
```

You can access the yourSchema.test.var in PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
my_var yourSchema.test.var%TYPE;
BEGIN
my_var := yourSchema.test.var;
END;
```

or get the value of var in SQL by using the function;

```
select yourSchema.test.get_var from dual;
```

In your package body you can initialize the value of var at load time or use the function to return the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below function in your package and call it using select from dual:

```
    create or replace function CHECK_FUNC
    return number
    AS
    var number;
    BEGIN
    var := 2+3;
    return var;
    END CHECK_FUNC;
    /
Function created.     

SQL> select 10 from dual where 10 > (select check_func from dual);
  -- 10 > (2+3) condition satisfied. Hence '10' is returned.                                                                                                

        10                                                                                                                  
----------                                                                                                                  
        10                                                                                                                  

SQL> select 10 from dual where 10 < (select check_func from dual);                                                          
        --10 < (2+3) condition NOT satisfied. Hence no rows returned.                                                                                                                        
no rows selected
```

Few more examples:

```
 select 'SOMETHING' from dual where 10 > (select check_func from dual); 

    'SOMETHIN                                                                                                                   
    ---------                                                                                                                   
    SOMETHING     


select 'SOMETHING' from dual where 10 < (select check_func from dual); 

no rows selected
```

Comment: The packge already exists and i need to access just one variable from it. So I believe declaring it in header is the only option left

Comment: I believe you want to use the variable value(check_func=5)  in select then you can use a function inside a package.